# Normalizer, and Centralizer of Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose we have $K,H \leq G$ and $K \subset H$, $H \subset N_{G}(K)$, how do I show that $H \subset N_{G}(C_{G}(K))$?

I know that $C_{G}(K) \leq N_{G}(K)$, and $H \leq N_{G}(K)$.

Just stating the problem, we have that $\forall h \in H$, $hKh^{-1} = K$, and we want to show that $\forall h \in H, hC_{G}(K)h^{-1} = C_{G}(K)$.

I am not sure how to proceed. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: It is difficult to parse what you are asking. Please separate off the exercise you don't understand how to do from the rest of the text/your attempt

Answer (score 2):

Let $u\in C_G(K)$, $h\in H$. You want to show that $huh^{-1}$ centralizes $K$. To that end, let $k\in K$; we want to show that
$$(huh^{-1})k(huh^{-1})^{-1} =k.$$

We have:
$$\begin{align*}
(huh^{-1})k(huh^{-1})^{-1} &= hu(h^{-1}kh)u^{-1}h^{-1}\\
&= h(h^{-1}kh)uu^{-1}h^{-1} &(*)\\
&= hh^{-1}khh^{-1}\\
&=k.
\end{align*}$$
where $(*)$ holds because $u$ commutes with every element of $k$, and $hkh^{-1}\in K$ since $h$ normalizes $K$.